# What is the stance of an "interfaith Nikah" due to husband's conversion?

Tags: nikah, conversion

As-Salamu Alaykum. I am a new convert. I come from a Christian family. My wife is not considering conversion herself or for the kids. She has no problem with me being a Muslim. Yet, she freely continues do haram things like cook bacon for her and the kids. Again, she is completely supportive of my conversion.

Is interfaith nikah in this instance permissible to Allah(SWT)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is permissible for a Muslim man to marry a Christian woman.

> #### حل لهم والمحصنات من المؤمنات والمحصنات من الذين أوتوا الكتاب من قبلكم
>
> [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from among the believers and chaste women from among those who were given the Scripture before you
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:5](http://quran.com/5/5)</sup>

By extension it is permissible for a convert to remain married to his Christian wife.

She and any non-Muslims in your family can continue to eat according to their religion. There might be certain exceptions e.g. if you have infant children who get suckled, in which case you should ask her to not consume haram food in that period.

Note that according to Islamic law any children who are not adults (below puberty) are going to be Muslims following your conversion. How to resolve this with your wife is something you are going to have to figure out.

Comment: Thank you for your swift and informative answer. I didn’t know that my my two youngest children are Muslims now. I will be respectful of my wife’s beliefs. Allahu Akbar!